# Is there a direct way to clean the Civi Cache?

Tags: cache

Cleaning the civi cache updates the Smart Groups immediately (instead of waiting 5 minutes).

Is there a way to clean the civi cache directly (instead of Menu>Administer>SystemSettings>Cleanupcache&updatepaths>Cleanup Caches)

(I am not a programmer, but I may be able to include it in a small php program, if I am told how to do it).

Comment: You could do an SQL query using phpAdmin on your database, but seems a bit fiddly when the UI way is easier.....

Comment: There is an SQL query which can clean the civi cache ?

Answer (score 2):

You will find different ways of clearing cache (as Jon mentions) documented [**HERE**](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#clearing-the-cache), but I agree with Tony that perhaps the UI would be easier - maybe it's just a question of adding a top menu item on the [**navigation menu**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/#the-navigation-menu) or a button that will trigger /civicrm/clearcache?

Hope this helps!
Tamar

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Tamar's suggestion:

Go to `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigation Menu`
Click `Add Menu Item`
Title: Clear Cache
Url: `/civicrm/clearcache`
Parent:  leave as Top level, or configure as you like
Click `Save`

Refresh the page and you should find a new entry in your menus to clear the cache.

Comment: Thank you Aidan and Tamar : /civicrm/clearcache is probably close to the solution I am looking for (it's a simple URL) and is OK for me as an admin ; but what permission should I grant to a user to run it ? ... + I am then driven to the civicrm/dashboard : I would like the user to remain on the same node : is this possible ?

Comment: BTW, what is the (php ?) program which runs clearcache ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of methods, but the easiest is probably to download `cv` and use `cv flush`.